# What does it mean when it says to use the same energy mix in this network? Also how do capacitors affect the short circuit?

Tags: short-circuit, distribution-network

Here is the network:

[image]

There is generator G1 that is modeled as a coal-fired power station and generators G2 and G2 that are modeled as a hydropower plant. It is said that if i reinforce the generation it must be done by maintaining the same energy mix.

Not sure what that exactly means, so if i add another generator saying it is a coal-fired power station i must another another generator as a hydro power plant to maintain the same energy mix? And also, if i add another generator, should i just add another one next to the existing ones in the same bus or can i add another generation to another bus?

Next question is when computing the three-phase symmetric short-circuit current in some bus in this network can i use the impedance matrix? I'll assume i will be easier this way but i am not sure. Also how do the capacitors Q1,Q2 and Q3 affect this computation? I never solved sc with capacitors

Comment: `It is said that ....` - it is said where?

Comment: You need to **ask your instructor** if you want clarification on a homework or exam question. That's the only way to make sure that you will get full credit for your answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a homework question with no attempt at a solution.